# "The jury in the E. Jean Carroll civil battery and defamation trial was made public Friday" meaning clarification

Tags: sentence-meaning

> The video deposition of Donald Trump played before **the jury in the E. Jean Carroll civil battery and defamation trial was made public Friday**, showing the former president discussing the accusations against him, the “Access Hollywood” tape and the Russia “hoax.”
>
> [The source](https://edition.cnn.com/2023/05/05/politics/trump-deposition-released-e-jean-carroll-trial/index.html)

I'm not quite sure what the sentence in bold is saying. I think it might be read:

1. the jury (a group of people who decide a verdict for the case) was disclosed to the public, so the public knows who they are and the name list.
2. the sentence also makes me think that somehow it might be relevant to the idiom "the jury is still out", which leads to completely different meaning.

I might think too much about it. Can anyone help to clarify the meaning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sentence is referring to a literal jury. It's a complex sentence, so let's just cut out some of the modifiers to get down to the basics. The barest essentials are:

The deposition was made public.

The subject of the sentence is "deposition". The verb is "was made". The object of the verb is "public".

That is, there was a deposition, and that deposition was made available to the public.

What kind of deposition? A "video deposition".

Specifically what video deposition? The "video deposition of Donald Trump".

Any more description of the deposition? Yes. "The video deposition of Donald Trump played before the jury."

That is, the sentence is about a deposition. This deposition is a video deposition. And this video was played for the jury.

What jury? "The jury in the E. Jean Carroll civil battery and defamation trial".

When was it made public? It was made public "Friday".

Finally, there is one more clause describing the video. We are told that it is "showing the former president discussing" etc.

Comment: You made my day! Originally, I took the word 'before' as a conjunction, instead of a prep. "in front of". So I misunderstood it and somehow confused.

Comment: Oh, yes. Here "before" means "in front of", and not "occurring earlier than". As in, "He stood before the flag". Not, "He arrived before you did."